# Storing data in global/session variables vs. MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

A general PHP question about organizing a website: for efficiency purposes, is it better to store data from MySQL queries into global arrays, or to make a new query every time data is needed? I am thinking specifically of a sports stats-oriented website, with a lot of data that does not necessarily change very often.
I have heard that storing the data into arrays is much more efficient, but I don't see how since global variables are only global in the scope of the current PHP page. Ideally, I'd like to populate all my arrays once I start my server. Should I use session variables then? I haven't heard of anybody doing that.

Comment: It may be profitable to use cache in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session variable won't resolve the issue, as the session is not global as well (unless you hack it by setting the same session_id to all visitors).

If you have a lot of traffic and you need to save queries, than use a cache server like memcached or redis.

If you can't install memcached or redis, you can create a PHP file that contains the arrays, and include it in the scripts - e.g. use file caching. The bad thing about this approach is that you will use a lot of memory - the whole data should be read in the memory by any PHP script, by any visitor. So in case the database is not the bottleneck, better keep the queries.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am already including a PHP file that contains the arrays -- but every time I include, it performs all the database queries. If I create a PHP file containing all the arrays, I don't need a database anymore...